# Howto build node-gyp on Windows 10?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Command on Windows 10:

```
npm i pg-native
```

Throws this build error:

```
λ npm i pg-native                                                                                                                      

> libpq@1.8.7 install C:\Users\User\MyProject\frontend\node_modules\libpq                                                      
> node-gyp rebuild                                                                                                                     


C:\Users\User\MyProject\frontend\node_modules\libpq>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm
\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users
\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )                                            
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.                            
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(55,5): error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual 
 Studio 2010 (Platform Toolset = 'v100') cannot be found. To build using the v100 build tools, please install Visual Studio 2010 build 
 tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution,  
and then selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\Users\User\MyProject\frontend\node_modules\libpq\build\addon.vcxproj]              
gyp ERR! build error                                                                                                                   
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1                                   
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23
)                                                                                                                                      
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)                                                                                       
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)                                                                              
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)                                           
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299                                                                                                  
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-g
yp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"                                                                                                        
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\User\MyProject\frontend\node_modules\libpq                                                               
gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.1                                                                                                                
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2                                                                                                            
gyp ERR! not ok
```

I have tried to install Visual Studio/ Express 2010 but it did not help. Also tried to install PostgreSQL 9.6 instead of 10, and add its bin directory to the path. That did not help.

The error message suggest to install build tools v100 but it is not possible on Windows 10. Not supported (or I don't know how?) The other suggested solution is to "Retarget the solution" but it is also impossible, because the given C:\Users\User\MyProject\frontend\node_modules\libpq\build\addon.vcxproj solution file does not exist, so it cannot be retargeted.

I'm new to node.js and I'm totally lost at the beginning. :-( Why don't npm have binary packages, like other languages do? (E.g. Python wheels, Java jars etc.) I just want to use basic libpq functions. Why do I have to install 2GB of toolchain for this, and then realize that it won't work? So much frustration.

By the way, I have also tried to install Windows SDK 7.1 because that contains the v100 platform toolset, but it cannot be installed on Windows 10.

Is there an easy way to install it as a binary? Is there anybody who could compile this on Windows 10?

There is no point in compiling with v100 anyway because it is a dinosaur. If the module MUST be compiled with a 10 years old compiler for some unknown reason (which I doubt), then it would still be much better to simply include the compiled binary in the package. (I happen to know that a 10 years old lipq.dll works fin with PostgreSQL 10.)

Comment: This is not relevant to `pg` or `pg-native`. This is only relevant to `node-gyp` module that requires that you install and properly configure a C++ compiler, in order to be able to install modules that require C++ compilation.

Comment: Okay maybe i should change the question then. But still, msvc v100 is not a "properly configured c++ compiler" but a dinosaur that cannot be properly configured on a modern os at all.

Comment: Why would you bother with such an ancient compiler? You can install a free version of VC++ 2015, for example. This is what I did, and it worked.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that later today. But the error message clearly says the the v100 build tools are missing. I suspect that even if you install VC++ 2015, the v100 build tools won't be installed. (And they cannot be installed on Win 10.) It might turn out that this can also be compiled with VC++ 2015, but then it means that the error message was wrong in the first place.

Comment: You need to look at how to configure `node_gyp` to use it properly. You haven't done it, and so it's looking for the wrong compiler.

Comment: All right. BTW the build/install instructions on the pg-native are wrong for sure, they also recommend installing Express 2010. I might be able to hand-configure and install node_gyp in the end, but I still feel this is not how things should be. Either dependent projects should be installed automatically, or at least the provided official installation instructions should be good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After serious number of hours working on this, here is the solution.

**NOTE**: the original question was about compiling pg-native. If you seek to compile node-gyp only, please ignore steps 1,2.

1. Install PostgreSQL 10 to your system.
2. Add the bin directory of your postgresql installation to your PATH system environment variable. Warning! It must be system env, not user env!
3. Make sure you have the latest npm installed.
4. Start a new elevated shell (cmd.exe or powershell). E.g. "run as administrator". If you did not restart your system after step 2, then make sure that you can run the "pg_config" program from that shell.
5. run the commands below, in this order, in the same terminal. do not close and reopen the terminal between two commands!

   ```
    npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
    npm install -g node-gyp
    npm install -g pg-native
   ```

Please note that installing node-gyp requires admin rights, so you must install it globally as admin, even if you only need it for one project. (I might be wrong, but this was my experience.)

Also note that I might be wrong in many other ways, I might not know what I was doing, but the above procedure actually solves the problem for sure. :-)

Comment: Please note that this answer is about installing pg-native, that depends on node-gyp. This is because the original question was about installing pg-native, but it turned out that the real problem is node-gyp.